# iOS: how to dequeue reusable 'default' cells without actually having a cell in storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I have several tables the default cells such as the one with title, or the one with icon on the left and title on the right.

I don't want to add those cells in storyboard and assign identifier to them, is it possible to do that?

It has to be reusable, I know how to alloc new non-reusable cells

I have tried the answers below,

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];
```

should be correct, but it's very tedious and easily forget

```
UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

The above maybe better since it puts all the code at one place, but when I try dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: (with indexPath) it crashes.

1. Why does dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath crashes while dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does not?
2. if i don't pass in indexPath, is the cell reusable
3. if it is reusable, then whats the use of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath?

Comment: Like Aviels answer but use `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` rather than loading from a Nib.

Comment: You don't need to register class if you use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method. However you DO need to register if you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:  Both methods will give you a reusable cell, but the former method will instantiate it for you, so you need to have a registered class or a prototype cell. The first method will fetch a cell with the given identifier in the reuse stack and return nil if none is present, you then have to instantiate the cell yourself

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you don't have any prototype cell in your storyboard, you can use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: api to create classic cell

```
UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

swift:

```
var cell : UITableViewCell!
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: so only for the first time it's allocated, then all the rest are dequeued?

Comment: r u sure u don't need to registerClass?

Comment: You don't need to register class if you use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method. However you DO need to register if you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: Both methods will give you a reusable cell, but the former method will instantiate it for you, so you need to have a registered class or a prototype cell. The first method will fetch a cell with the given identifier in the reuse stack and return nil if none is present, you then have to instantiate the cell yourself

Comment: Does this add the created cell back into the pool for reuse later?

Comment: Update: seems like it does in my testing. Which means when creating the cell with identifier, it is stored in the pool and taken to be used later. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

### Swift 3.0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {
        return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        return cell
    }()
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = anyArray[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
}
```

It is good, because give cell unwrapped.

Comment: I think you are sometimes returning a cell without textLabel?.text set.

Comment: @vharron suggest a edit)

Answer (score 15):

You can dequeue a UITableViewCell without having a prototype cell in your storyboard. You need to register the cell with your table for a specific identifier (string). You would do this like so:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];
```

You could do this in `viewDidLoad`, maybe.

Then, you can dequeue a cell using that identifier in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as usual.

Edit:

Where `MyCellIdentifier` is a constant you have defined somewhere, of course.

Comment: I wouldn't call registering UITableViewCell for an identifier very tedious, it is only one line of code :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to try to dequeue the cell, and if you get `nil` than create it. In the cell xib file define it's identifier.

**Set the cell identifier in the nib file:**

[image: Set cell identifier]

**Get a reusable cell or make a new one:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myCell";
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *t = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myCellXibFileName" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in t)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyCell class]])
            {
                cell = (MyCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Do whatever you want with the cell....
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the whole idea of this question is not to have a cell in xib or storyboard

Comment: Your question said nothing about xib, only storyBoard, and since storyBoard is managing cells different than xib (By letting you only call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and always get a cell) I understood from your question that you seek to use xib file for your cell instead of putting it inside the tableView in your storyboard. Please be more clear next time.

Answer (score 0):

Open components library, drag a UITableViewCell into your TableView storyboard, and select this cell to open the identity inspector, then select the default style you want and set the cell identifier as same as the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in your code.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4, Swift 5

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = user[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ">"
    return cell
}
```

There are 4 Default UITableViewCell Style: default, value1, value2 & subtitle. Learn more at
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/cellstyle

Comment: This code skips reuse from the the cell pool completely.